# Access get a list and total count of distinct items

Tags: ms-access

I've been trying to find an Access version of the subject and testing many concepts.  All I want to do is what I thought was simple.  Let's say I have a single column in a table.  Values are like

California
Florida
California
California
New York
California
New York

let's leave it that simple.  All I'm trying to do which seems easy in SQL Server or Oracle is show the distinct values and how many times they are referenced in the table.  So output would be:

California  4
Florida  1
New York 2

On Access 2019 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL; would be the same in SQL-Server, Oracle, MsAccess (and almost all other SQL dialects); just use:

```
select State, count(*)
from YourTbl
group by State
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I was overthinking this with trying the distinct count path.  One other question.  I need to find the count of unique locations but deeper than state.  In our system we have "tags".  So a tech enters a tag for the state, and a tag for the building, and a tag for the floor for a piece of equipment.  They could show up when exported to access in any of the three tag columns.  So tag1, tag2, tag3.  Any way to find counts of distinct values that match across all three tags but could be in any order in the tags?  Make sense?  Can provide an example outside the comment block.

Comment: Could you submit that as a separate question? it really needs example data and expected result

Comment: still... provide an example here, if you wish